# How to randomly disable buttons in java

Tags: java, random, jbutton

I have this program where I need to randomly disable some buttons so that the user is not able to select all of them. Is there a way to disable random buttons in java?

I was thinking of using `Math.random`, but I don't know how to start or refer to it.....

These are the buttons.

```
JButton but1 = new JButton();
JButton but2 = new JButton();
JButton but3 = new JButton();
JButton but4 = new JButton();
JButton but5 = new JButton();
JButton but6 = new JButton();
JButton but7 = new JButton();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array/Vararg Verson:

```
public JButton getRandomButton(JButton... buttons) {
    int index = (int) (Math.random() * buttons.length);

    return buttons[index];
}
```

List Version:

```
public JButton getRandomButton(List<JButton> buttons) {
    int index = (int) (Math.random() * buttons.size());

    return buttons.get(index);
}
```

Both methods will return a random JButton for you to do stuff with.

Comment: Yes thank you so much, it's working!
It doesn't really matter but is it possible to like also randomly disable more than one buttons at a time, or maybe sometimes it disables 2 buttons or 3 buttons. Thank you so much tho
P.S I used **Array/Vararg Verso**

Comment: Just call the method multiple times and you'll get multiple buttons back. Just keep in mind that you may get the same button multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You can put them all in a list, then shuffle the list and disable the element at index 0 for example...

but note that:

- it could happen that you are disabling an already disabled button, so you need to do some checks
- shuffling a list is an operation that will require more time, and it depends on how many buttons you have in the list.

---

```
List<JButton> items = Arrays.asList(new JButton(), new JButton(), new JButton());
System.out.println(items);
Collections.shuffle(items);
items.get(0).setEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your buttons into a `List` and iterate over them. Use [`Random.nextBoolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBoolean--) to determine whether to enable or disable the button. This will give you a 50/50 distribution. If you require something else, use `nextInt` and a modulus.

```
List<JButton> myButtons = /*whatever*/;

final Random generator = new Random();
for (JButton button : myButtons)
{
    button.setEnabled(generator.nextBoolean());
}
```

This won't guarantee that any number of the buttons are enabled at any one time. You weren't clear whether that was important.